# Django admin site gives error on Djangae

Tags: django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a Django app that works perfectly on google app engine, using the datastore via djangae. However, the admin site throws an error:

```
NotSupportedError at /admin/auth/user/5629499534213120/change/

Cross-join where filters are not supported on the Datastore
```

This error only occurs when trying to edit the default Django user model. Not sure why this is happening.

I have used the default Django user model. (this is an app dealing with donations for a nonprofit)

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.


class FoodSplashUser(models.Model):
    base_user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    address = models.TextField(null=True)
    city = models.TextField(null=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=4, null=True)
    zip = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.base_user.username)


class Organization(models.Model):
    base_user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    address = models.TextField(null=True)
    city = models.TextField(null=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=4, null=True)
    zip = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)

    description = models.TextField(null=True)
    image_url = models.URLField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.base_user.username)


class DonationRequest(models.Model):
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    request_type = models.TextField(null=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.organization.base_user.username) + " " + self.request_type


class DonationPromise(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(FoodSplashUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    donation_request = models.ForeignKey(DonationRequest, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user.base_user.username) + " " + str(self.donation_request)
```

This app goes with the default Django admin interface, but I decided to make the classes below for easy editing later.

admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from . import models

# Register your models here.


class FoodSplashUserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass


class OrganizationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass


class DonationRequestAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass


class DonationPromiseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass


admin.site.register(models.FoodSplashUser, FoodSplashUserAdmin)
admin.site.register(models.Organization, OrganizationAdmin)
admin.site.register(models.DonationRequest, DonationPromiseAdmin)
admin.site.register(models.DonationPromise, DonationPromiseAdmin)
```

Comment: If possible, can you add your models.py and admin.py file?

Comment: @CoolestNerdIII I just did

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a separate error, but :

```
admin.site.register(models.DonationRequest, DonationPromiseAdmin)
admin.site.register(models.DonationPromise, DonationPromiseAdmin)
```

Shouldn't that first one be: `DonationRequestAdmin`?

Comment: that is a different error but thanks for catching it

Answer (score 0):

`NotSupportedError` indicates that your code performs an action that is not possible with App Engine Datastore. Not all the Django ORM features can be used in a non-relational database which Datastore is. You are trying to create an entity that has some relations, which causes the error. Probably it is a good idea to use [Gauth](https://djangae.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gauth/) for authentication and user management, as described in the Djangae docs.

Comment: The user auth system works fine. It is just the Django admin user management page that has this issue.

Comment: Have you seen this [Google Groups thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/djangae-users/8AsVyBNtNt4)? Somebody had the same error and was advised by the Djangae folks to use what is specified in Gauth docs. It helps to overcome the many-to-many relationship issues with Datastore.

Comment: When I follow those instructions I get: `'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'session'` And Yes, I have `'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware'` in my middleware